# One time javascript function run in custom action

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have a request from the customer that they want every time they create a subsite (publishing site) .We have to add a custom column to OOTB Documents list.

> I have done some researching the way to add the custom column to
>   Documents list in **onet.xml** but have no luck .
>
> Then i think about the work around solution that i create a
>   **ScriptBlock custom action** that will call javascript function which
>   will add the custom column to document list , then i will put this
>   custom action to a feature ,and finally i will reference that feature
>   in onet.xml.

It run well but the javascript function call every time i refresh the page. I just want it run one time when i active the feature.
Does anyone have any suggestion ? *I use sandbox solution and Sharepoint Online* .Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a custom action is the right way to do this, Custom actions generally need some sort of user interaction.

- Get CKS dev tools in Visual studio
- Create a new SharePoint solution
- Add a new web template(CKS Dev) to your solution from the Add new item menu in VS
- Create an additional feature (web) with a list template (Your documents Library and add your column)
- Update the Web templates onet file

Also sometimes it's better to put up what your having issues with as you have said you have had no luck with the above, What is the issue you are having, Post some code up etc rather than going down the route of changing the way you implement the solution

Many Thanks

Truez